# isotope.js - initialize after Angular rendered DOM

Tags: angularjs, load, jquery-isotope

Well, this is giving this angular newbie some gray hairs:

My regular isotope external javascript initialization begins like normal :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// ISOTOPE INITIALISATON AND STUFF HERE
```

And that all works fine with no angular. Now since my isotope items is in a separate portfolio.html page which loads  into my main index.html page which contains an ng-view div, isotope sometimes fails to initialize.

It's around fifty fifty: If I refresh isotope works, then it doesn't. So this is due to that angular is not ready renderinng the DOM. And so even though I am waiting for document ready (and tried document load), that does not work either.

Is there a simple way that I can create my isotope AFTER that my index.html page loaded my portfolio.html page in (where my portfolio contains my isotope divs), with Angular?

Please note I am not using angular-isotope but just the regular metafizzy isotope and angular.

A simple as possible solution would be great:
Somehow I must create my isotope after that the Angular is done. But how do I call a method in my main.js file(which is the file where I initialize my Isotope) from my Script.js file (which is the file with my Angular script)

If it is any help this is my angular script:

```
// script.js

// create the module and name it scotchApp
    // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});


// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Hmmm.hmmmm. I think it is time for a cup of tea. Hmm. hmm

Look forward to your replies!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

I simply added this line to my isotope javascript file

```
$(window).load(function() { window.setTimeout(onRenderReadyStartIsotope, 0) });
```

And the intialised isotope with that timedout function call. Was no need for me this time to look into directives or change the angular, the DOM now renders, the isotope begins.